# whats faster search in mysql: table with one column or many smaller columns

Tags: mysql, search

Im trying to build a table for search on consolidated data from many different tables. All columns are strings. I'm not sure whats faster way:

1. Combine all strings into one column (each string separated by |)
   like "94045|Mountain View|blah|..."
2. Make table with multiple String columns.

I plan to do "LIKE" search. For example  "select id from SEARCH where col1 like '%view%'"

Is there any difference in terms of search speed between 2 approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `id` is your primary key and you're using InnoDB.

If the combined strings are less than the InnoDB single column index limit of 767 bytes, then combine the strings into one column so that MySQL can scan a single, flat index. Then, create a secondary index on that single column.

Because of the wildcard in the prefix, MySQL will still have to scan the index rather than doing a binary search to locate the ids, but scanning an index is faster than scanning the much larger data pages.

In addition, given enough working room (`innodb_buffer_pool_size`), MySQL will have the index in memory, so it won't have to hit the disk at all.

```
SELECT id FROM table1
WHERE column1 LIKE '%search%'
```

Note that the single column index acts as a *covering index* here because InnoDB secondary indexes always have the primary key also. So, selecting only `id`, the primary key, against a secondary index, treats it as a covering index.

Comment: thank you for explanation. So in my case size of the 767 bytes is main factor. And what if I go above that size?

Comment: Then you'll be performing a table scan, which really means scanning the much larger clustered index, which has the actual data on each page. These can be stored in memory too, but this means that your innodb_buffer_pool_size would have to be much bigger. Assuming a single column primary key, it's already flat, so joining or separating the columns won't much make difference at this point. All along, I'm assuming you're talking about real char or varchar columns, not text or other blob columns because that changes everything.

Answer (score 1):

If each separated word has a different meaning, then separated columns should be better. 
For instance, if your data is composed from: zip code, street and description, then you should have 3 different columns for that.

This way, you can construct your search to look only on certain fields, if you know the search term should only be in one of the fields.

Comment: From data type point all columns are equal. If user types "94" I should find either street address with that number, name of city or ZIP code.

Answer (score 1):

If the search pattern has a wildcard before the first character, there is no way to index the data effectively for a fast search, so a "full data scan" is needed.

You can greatly improve the performance by reducing the number of records scanned.  Like inspect the data to pick out the zip code and do an indexed search for it (combined with the mad `LIKE` condition).

Comment: I do need to find search string anywhere inside column strings. So yes it going to be ugly. Any advice on better solution for that kind of search? Even dropping MySQL and picking different DB is an option.